# Reference another attribute in InverseBindingAdapter

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have the following `BindingAdapter` for a `TextView` showing a date:

```
@BindingAdapter(value = {"date", "minDate", "maxDate", "dateFormat", "dateAttrChanged"}, requireAll = false)
public static void bindDate(TextView textView, Long date, Long minDate, Long maxDate,
                            String dateFormat, final InverseBindingListener dateChangedListener) {
    DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat != null? dateFormat : "dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.GERMAN);
    textView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(date != null ? date : System.currentTimeMillis());
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(textView.getContext(), (dateView, year, month, dayOfMonth) -> {
            Calendar result = Calendar.getInstance();
            result.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
            textView.setText(dateFormatter.format(result.getTimeInMillis()));
            if(dateChangedListener != null) {
                dateChangedListener.onChange();
            }
        }, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        if(minDate != null) {
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minDate);
        }
        if(maxDate != null){
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxDate);
        }
        datePickerDialog.show();
    });
    textView.setClickable(true);
    textView.setFocusable(true);
    if(date != null) {
        textView.setText(dateFormatter.format(date));
    }

    // todo find a way to pass the dateFormat to InverseBindingAdapter
    textView.setTag(dateFormat);
}

@Nullable
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "date", event = "dateAttrChanged")
public static Long bindDate(TextView textView) {
    DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(textView.getTag() != null ?
            (String) textView.getTag() : "dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.GERMAN);
    Long result = null;
    try {
        result = dateFormatter.parse(String.valueOf(textView.getText())).getTime();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is there any way to reference the `dateFormat` attribute in the `InverseBindingAdapter` (passing it's value via the tag is the current workaround)?

Comment: I don't think there's another way other than your work-around. You should put in a feature request!

Comment: @GeorgeMount Can you post a link for the right feature request site?